# $P(z)-zQ(z)=0$ having no solution in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

I am currently reading "Iteration of Rational Functions" by Alan F. Beardon and my Question is about the beginning of $§2.6.$ which deals with Fixed points. Given a rational function $R=P/Q$ where $P,Q$ are coprime polynomials. If $z_0 \neq \infty$ is fixed by $R$, then $Q(z_0)\neq 0$ and $P(z_0)=z_0Q(z_0).$ It is now stated that the fixed points of $R$ in $\mathbb{C}$ are the solutions of $P(z)-zQ(z)=0$.

After that it is noted that this need not have any solutions in $\mathbb{C}$ and the counter example given is $z \mapsto z+\frac{1}{z}$.

So far so good. My question is now that I do not see how to get this counterexample with the given solution.

Comment: In this counterexample we have ${\rm deg}(P)=2$ and ${\rm deg}(Q)=1$. I don't get your question. It's just an example for an $R$ which have no fixed foint in $\Bbb C$. Also, e.g. $R(z)=z+c$ could work work any constant $c\ne 0$.

Comment: For no solutions to exist $P(z) - z Q(z)$ must be a constant non-0 polynomial. The given counterexample uses $Q(z)=z$ and $P(z) = z Q(z) + 1\,$, so that  $R(z)=\frac{z^2+1}{z}=z+\frac{1}{z}\,$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I did not realise that $R(z)=\frac{z^2+1}{z}=z+\frac{1}{z}$. Additionally, I thought about higher degree polynomials, respectively a higher difference in degrees, and was confused due to the fundamental theorem of algebra. My bad I did ignore the lower degree ones. You like to add your comment as an answer @dxiv? I find your answer comprehensible and short, especially  that $P(z) - z Q(z)$ must be a constant non-0 polynomial

Comment: 'It is trivial to see' that Beardon is very nonchalant. So if you don't understand something from initial visual inspection then you might want to write down some scratch work; because surely Beardon did the same at some point (back when dinosaurs existed or whatever -_-).

Comment: Haha, that is good to know, since I just began to read and work with it. Somehow I just thought that $z+\frac{1}{z}$ meant an example for $P(z)-zQ(z)$ for some $P,Q$

Comment: an allusive way of imparting some insight in regards to why he casually says, "if $z_0 \neq \infty$"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Expanded from the posted comment*.)

For no solutions to exist, $P(z)-zQ(z)$ must be a constant non-0 polynomial (*otherwise if $\deg (P-zQ) \ge 1$ then it would have a root by the [FTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra), else if $P \equiv 0$ then $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}$ would be a root*). Therefore no solutions exist iff $P(z) = z Q(z) + c$ for some $c \ne 0$.

The given counterexample uses $Q(z)=z$ and $c=1\,$, so that $P(z)=z\cdot z+1=z^2+1$ and $R(z)=\cfrac{z^2+1}{z}=z+\cfrac{1}{z}\,$.